# Unable to connect to oracle database.It says "Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource"

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I have used spring boot in my project and I have the few properties of my oracle database that needs to be specified.They are:

```
Schema Name=OWNER
Password=OWNER
Database Name=DCGCDB
```

It is located in my server so the IP to connect is 192.168.1.5 and the Port Number is 1521.

So in my `application.properties` file i have made some settings to connect database and here it is:

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:192.168.1.5:1521:DCGCDB
spring.datasource.username=OWNER
spring.datasource.password=OWNER
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
#logging.level.=debug
```

But when building the project I am getting error like:

```
o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to determine jdbc url from
datasource org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
not establish the connection    at
org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328)
```

I have added the oracle jar file in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And also executed the statement `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=oracle-ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar` to install the oracle jar file.

Comment: Wrong Dialekt?!

Comment: what is the change i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver) page, the way you have defined your JDBC URL is wrong. That needs correction firstly, from this:

**Old JDBC URL**: `jdbc:oracle:thin:192.168.1.5:1521:DCGCDB`

to this:

**New JDBC URL**: `jdbc:oracle:thin@//192.168.1.5:1521/YourOracleServiceName`

Considering `DCGCDB` is your Oracle's Service name.

Secondly, there is a difference in the dialect that is being used for Oracle. I don't know why!!!

You could possibly use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` for the dialect instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: You're welcome @ashwinkarki. Glad that I could be of help!